# Combining String and Variable causes leading extra Space

Tags: powershell, concatenation

Ok so simple one here but i couldn't find an awnser myself:

Code:

```
$days=730
Write-Host "Starting Inactivityscan for Accounts with treshhold ["$days"] Days."
```

System Output:

```
Starting Inactivityscan for Accounts with treshhold [ 730] Days.
```

Why is there a leading space in Front of the `$days` variable?
How can i print the string without the leading space?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `$days`, you passing multiple arguments rather than concatenating. Or wrap everything in a subexpression `$()` to evaluate prior to passing to `write-host`

Comment: @BenH oh shuut, thanks, i didn't know i could concatenate variables like that.